# Why does my 'npm install' give so many vulnerabilities?

Tags: npm

Everytime I do npm install after cloning a github project OR install packages on my local system for my practice projects, there are always around 20+ vulnerabilities.
But the guys in youtube tutorials always have 0 vulnerabilities.

I even reinstalled npm but it didn't change anything

Comment: try the command `npm install your_package@latest` The @latest part will give you the most recent version of the package that may have the vulnerabilities fixed

Comment: It's probably because package management for even a medium-sized project is a constant battle, as new vulnerabilities are being discovered every day. What if you run `npm audit fix`? Does that help you?

Comment: because decencies are old and they are way behind than stable/latest version of that package. So to update the dependencies use `npm update [...package_name]` but before doing this I recommend checking repo once, may be new versions have breaking changes and if so you need  to update your code to match those requirements.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie  npm audit fix doesn't help at all. But I didn't know there are new vulnerabilities frequently coming up. I'll search it up once again. Thanks

Comment: @bogdanoff I see, but if I am contributing to an open-source project, how significant are these vulnerabilities (generally)? can I ignore them even if I have around 10 high vulnerabilities?

Comment: @SohamParate Its completely depends on ['Severity'](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln-metrics/cvss) score, if severity is high or critical, you should resolve that asap (especially if it is high).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are following an old video, you are likely installing old packages. Therefore it's pretty common to have vulnerabilities.

If you want the warnings to disappear, you can try to remove `@version` in your packages inside `package.json` and then run `npm i` again. Or, as bogdanoff says, run `npm update` instead.

But be careful: packages may behave differently from the video when updated.

Comment: I see, so can I safely ignore vulnerabilities when running npm install while contributing to other projects?

Comment: It depends what you mean for safely. Nothing is 100% safe, not even work on updated packages. Check npm auditing page: https://docs.npmjs.com/auditing-package-dependencies-for-security-vulnerabilities